# radio button not doing it's action

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

Every time I click the radio button for in2cm and try to convert, there is nothing showing when I click the convert button. If possible also show me how to use a list box, so I will just put it on a list box and make the GUI much more easier to use.

```
ButtonGroup convertgroup=new ButtonGroup();
jr=new JRadioButton[10];

jr[0]=new JRadioButton("Inch to Cm");

l1 = new JTextField(25);
l2 = new JTextField(25);

length1 = new JLabel("ft", SwingConstants.LEFT);
length2 = new JLabel("cm", SwingConstants.LEFT);

convertgroup.add(jr[0]);

jr[1]=new JRadioButton("Meter to Feet");
length = new JLabel("m    = ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
l1 = new JTextField(25);
l2 = new JTextField(25);

length1 = new JLabel("ft", SwingConstants.LEFT);
length2 = new JLabel("cm", SwingConstants.LEFT);

convertgroup.add(jr[1]);

jr[2]=new JRadioButton("Mile to Km");
Mi2Km = new JTextField(25);
Km2Mi = new JTextField(25);
length3 = new JLabel("Mile", SwingConstants.LEFT);
length4 = new JLabel("Km", SwingConstants.LEFT);

convertgroup.add(jr[2]);

jr[3]=new JRadioButton("Nautical Mile to Km");
Nmi2Km= new JTextField(25);
Km2Nmi= new JTextField(25);

jr[4]=new JRadioButton("League to Km");
Le2Km = new JTextField(25);
Km2Le = new JTextField(25);

submit = new JButton("Convert");
clear = new JButton("Clear");
quit = new JButton("Quit");

submit.addActionListener(this);
clear.addActionListener(this);
quit.addActionListener(this);

converterPanel.add(jr[0]);
converterPanel.add(jr[2]);
converterPanel.add(jr[1]);
converterPanel.add(l1);
converterPanel.add(length);
converterPanel.add(l2);
converterPanel.add(length1);
converterPanel.add(jr[3]);
converterPanel.add(jr[4]);

converterPanel.add(submit);
converterPanel.add(clear);
converterPanel.add(quit);

length.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
```

Here is the action performed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if (event.getSource() == quit) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (event.getSource() == clear) {
        l1.setText("");
        l2.setText("");
    }

    if (event.getSource()== submit) {

        if(!jr[0].isSelected() && !jr[1].isSelected() && !jr[2].isSelected())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(converterFrame,
                    "No RadioButton has been Selected ", "Warning",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        if(jr[0].isSelected())
            in2cm();

        if(jr[1].isSelected()){
            lengthConvert();

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have found the problem and fixed it, but how can i change the jlabel every time the jr[0] is selected? because the jlabel in jr[1] is m and feet, and in jr[0] i need to make it in and cm.

Comment: Please show us the `actionPerformed` method .

Comment: i have added the actionPerformed method

Comment: I don't see anywhere you register an `ActionListener` to any of the radio buttons

Comment: public class Converter implements ActionListener {

this one?

Comment: Also, could you add the methods that don't seem to work ? `in2cm()` and `lengthConvert()`

Comment: So you want to change a JLabel's text? Just make it a member and use `setText` to change text. I think i couldn't understand you problem.